Flutter Riverpod `ref.watch` keeps staying at loading state after Hot Restart?
This is my first Flutter project, and I follow some instructions on YouTube on how to build a social network with it.
The problem I usually encounter is that after Hot Restart, specifics StreamProvider keeps staying at the loading state, even though I print logs to see if there was value from Firebase or not, and it does!!!
NewfeedsScreen.dart:
              ref.watch(getCommunitiesPostsProvider).when(
                    data: (posts) {
                      final hasPost = posts.isNotEmpty;
                      return !hasPost
                          ? const SliverToBoxAdapter(
                              child: Text(
                                'NOTHING',
                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                              ),
                            )
                          : SliverList(
                              delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                                (context, index) {
                                  final post = posts[index];
                                  return ref
                                      .watch(getUserDataProvider(post.uid))
                                      .when(
                                        data: (author) {
                                          return ref
                                              .watch(getCommunityByIdProvider(
                                                  post.communityId))
                                              .when(
                                                data: (community) {
                                                  if (community == null) {
                                                    return const ErrorText(
                                                      error:
                                                          'Unexpected Error Happened...',
                                                    );
                                                  }
                                                  return PostContainer(
                                                    author: author,
                                                    post: post,
                                                    community: community,
                                                  );
                                                },
                                                error: (error, stackTrace) =>
                                                    ErrorText(
                                                        error:
                                                            error.toString()),
                                                loading: () => const Loading(),
                                              );
                                        },
                                        error: (error, stackTrace) => Container(
                                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
                                            child: ErrorText(
                                                error: error.toString())),
                                        loading: () => const Loading(),
                                      );
                                },
                                childCount: posts.length,
                              ),
                            );
                    },
                    error: (error, stackTrace) => SliverToBoxAdapter(
                      child: ErrorText(
                        error: error.toString(),
                      ),
                    ),
                    loading: () =>
                        const SliverToBoxAdapter(child: Loading()),
                  ),

getCommunitiesPostsProvider:
final getCommunitiesPostsProvider = StreamProvider((ref) {
  return ref
      .watch(newsfeedControllerProvider.notifier)
      .getJoinedCommunitiesPosts();
});

getJoinedCommunitiesPosts():
  //GET THE COMMUNITIES BY CURRENT USER
  Stream<List<Post>> getJoinedCommunitiesPosts(String uid) {
    return _communityMembership
        .where('uid', isEqualTo: uid)
        .snapshots()
        .asyncMap((data) async {
      final communitiesId =
          data.docs.map((doc) => doc['communityId'] as String).toList();
      final List<Post> posts = [];
      for (var communityId in communitiesId) {
        final communityPosts =
            await _posts.where('communityId', isEqualTo: communityId).get();
        for (var postDoc in communityPosts.docs) {
          posts.add(
            Post.fromMap(postDoc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>),
          );
        }
      }
      return posts;
    });
  }

Before Hot Restart:
enter image description here
After Hot Restart:
enter image description here
I tried many ways to find the solutions, but still, it remained a mystery to me :(

because when you makes hot reload the objects are reloaded, but not their initilization. thus you should exit and re-enter in the page, and it should work
